# JPA CasCade Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

Suppose following class A,

```
    import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table_a")
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "a_id"))
    public class A {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
        private User user;

        @Column(name = "date")
        private DateTime date;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "number")
        private Integer number;
    }
```

Generic save method:

```
public T save(T entity) throws PersistenceException {
    this.getEntityManager().joinTransaction();
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        this.getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } else {
        entity = this.getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

In above class, User is a separate entity which has its own table in DB (user_table). Meaning User entity can be saved separately without using A class.
My problem is when i persist class A, it will persist/merge changes of User objects in to user_table. User entity in this relationship is just a reference property, i don't want to save/merge User entity when A class being saved.
How do i do that?

Iam using,

- hibernate 4.3.7.Final
- Java 1.8.66
- J2ee 7
- EJB 3
- Wildfly 8.2 Final

ps: save method of repository of A class is called by a Stateless(EJB) manager class.

Comment: The default value for CascaseType is none, which means do not save associated entities. You can try by putting this annotation @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.NONE), but as per my feeling, some where you are explicity adding the User Entity in database in your code as there is not CascaseType provided. May be debugging your code may help you.

Comment: Thanks @HarbeerKadian, it seems issue happens if the User entity is already in the persistent context. Meaning if the User entity is already loaded and state has been changed. So when A class being persisted, this modified User also get persisted. Seems like when persisting A class, whole persistent context get flushed. May be adding flushmode= COMMIT to persistence xml should fix the issue?

Comment: Since it is a referenced property, you are not supposed to change the User properties in A .right?If you are modifying User associated with A, meaning you are changing the association to some other user than the existing one. Think on it

Comment: @TomSebastian, thanks, Iam not completely replacing the User property, For some other reason state of the User property of A class can be changed, and it is the desired behavior.